# Struts2 redirectAction is not https?

Tags: java, ssl, struts2, https, struts

One of my result mapping type is a `"redirectAction"` in `struts.xml`
which when executed constructs a NON secure link... Why is that?
I wanted to constructs secure link using `"redirectAction"`
what should I do?

```xml
<result type="redirectAction" name="auth_stat">
    <param name="actionName">auth_stat</param>
</result>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a redirect result

```
<result type="redirect" name="auth_stat">
    <param name="location">https://www.yourserver.com/auth_stat</param>
</result>
```