# MVC modal login form redirect to upload form in modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, forms, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal

I have a scenario here. developing a  onepage application where clients can submit a photo in a modal form. But before they are able to do this they must be authenticated- if they click on the popup link to submit their photo and they are not authenticated a login or register page should show in the modal popup after they login or register, I want to redirect them still in the modal or a different modal the initial form for photo upload.

I am able to  display in a modal a login/register page  or the upload/submit form but I am wondering if what I am looking at could even work in a modal.  If anyone has experience in doing this I will be glad to receive direction.
I have seen this [page which is promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950603/how-to-redirect-from-one-bootstrap-modal-to-another-modal-on-success-in-struts-2)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use two different modals and show the relevant one?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check on upload photo modal button click , that user is authenticated or not , if it is authenticated then open upload photo modal , otherwise open login / register modal or redirect to login / register page.

you can use jquery to open modal , check if user is logged in or not and then triggle modal open event using jquery.